# Cell Displayed As a Single Column in Octave

Tags: octave

I am working on a .mat file containing different data. The problem is the Cell is shown as a single column, not as 2D form. I already tried `full('Cell')`, but it is still shown as a single column. Also I tried 
`size('Cell')` and `ismatrix('Cell')`, the answers were `53*45` and `1`.

Here is link of screenshot:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vsrx2a&s=8

Comment: Do you not just have a `m*1` matrix? Check using `size(YourMatrix)`.

Comment: My German is a bit rusty, but doesnt *Zusatzaufgaben* imply homework? Then it's probably wise to do it yourself, so you can learn something from it.

Comment: Hi Ken, seems the screenshot is on you rlocal Z-Drive - hard to access from abroad.

Comment: it is actually 53*45 matrix, I checked.

Comment: It is not a homework, stop guessing around;)

Comment: In that case: add a [mcve] detailing your code. Then we can see what we're dealing with instead of traipsing around in the dark.

Comment: Your screenshot does not look like matlab, is this octave?

Comment: 1) Which version of MATLAB you use? 2) Do you load the .mat file into the global workspace previous previewing your matrix, or you look at it directly from you "Import data..." wizard?  3) If loaded into the global workspace, do you use the Variable Editor, or the Command Window to display your matrix? 3) If in Command Window, what do you type to display your matrix?

Comment: This is not a valid matrix. It has strings in the first column and numbers in the second.

Comment: You are printing a cell in octave, not a matrix in matlab. Please update your question!

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers. Now I found a new way to reformulate my question.

Comment: 1.To answer Daniel and CST_Link questions, your guess is very right, I am using Octave 4.0.0. 2. My current directory is where the mat.file lies and I used s=load('EIOPA.mat'). So I used global workspace. 3. s is a structure data, so it contains different layers. The cell is in the 3rd layer: s.RFR_Str_lists.C2D_list_curncy, I used command window. 4. I used s.RFR_Str_lists.C2D_list_curncy to display the cell.

Comment: To Adriaan: Before I knew it was _cell_, I think it was impossible for me to reproduce codes, since I received the data from EIOPA. I did not even know what it is, I even believed it was matrices. That's why I did not provide any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your cell to a dataframe using `dataframe('cell')`, so that you can read the data in a table-form.